# Distance to circle inside triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I apologise for the lack of a precise term or title, math isn't my strong suit.

I'm trying to calculate the length of L, given angle A and radius of circle D, so that lines b and c tangents with circle D.

[image: Image of problem]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Using the definition of sine and the orthogonality of the tangent one has
$$\sin\left(\alpha/2\right)=\frac{\text{radius}}{\text{distance from center}}$$

Comment: It's actually $3/\sin(\dots)$. Moreover, fortunately, since $$\sin(45/2)=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2},$$ you even have a closed form for the distance

Comment: Sorry I messed up my previous comment. To repeat:
So given radius 3 and angle 45 that would be $$\sin\left(45/2\right)=\frac{3}{\text{distance from center}}$$
And that isolated would be
$$\text{distance from center}=\frac{3}{\sin\left(45/2\right)}$$

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, first time formatting equations, so that took at bit. No previews for comments. :)

Comment: No worries! glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

Supplementary to [b00n heT](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/119285/b00n-het)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3309388/651395):

Let's call the intersection of $b$ with the circunference $R$ and $r=d(R,D)$, the radius of the circumference.

Considering the right-angle triangle [ARD], we have that $\sin(RÂD)=\frac{r}{L}$, from the [definition of the $\sin$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) of an angle.

Then, if $A=2RÂD$, then: $$\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)=\frac{r}{L} \Leftrightarrow L=\frac{r}{\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: But in my example [ARD] isn't a right angled triangle, right?

Comment: $b=AR$, $b$ is tangent to the circumference in the point $R$, therefore, $RD\perp b$, so, $\sphericalangle ARD$ is a right angle, its amplitude is 90 degrees. Note that the point $R$ is not represented in your picture, I "created" that point. So, $[ARD]$ is a right angled triangle. See [tangent line in Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent) for more information.

Comment: Ah yeah, makes sense. I don't know what I was imagining. It's obviously right angled. :D

Answer (score -1):

L = R / Sin(A/2)

where R is the radius of the circle and A is the angle